# Java handshake_failure

Tags: java, handshake, handshaking

I am trying to code a discord bot for my discord server at the moment and want to include a stats command for various games. I have everything setup and it actually works, but there is one problem: when I use a stats command for the first time after the start of the bot everything is fine, but when i then try a different user, i get a handshake_failure

This is the code that gets excecuted when i type the command in discord to get the website content from the stats website:

```
URL url = new URL("https://rocketleague.tracker.network/profile/steam/" + args[0]);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        String line;
        String content = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            content += line + '\n';
        }
        reader.close();
```

args[0] is the username.

The error I get is the following:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:128)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:279)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:163)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
at Commands.RLStats.action(RLStats.java:27)
at Commands.Stats.action(Stats.java:44)
at Core.CommandHandler.handleCommand(CommandHandler.java:17)
at Listeners.CommandListener.onMessageReceived(CommandListener.java:15)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:411)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:84)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:127)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:37)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:868)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:766)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:745)
at net.dv8tion.jda.core.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:903)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:368)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:270)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:990)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:749)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

I hope somebody can help me here, because I have absolutely no Idea what to do